# How safe is stripping leading '/' and disallowing '../' from user input filepaths?

Tags: file-upload, sanitize, sanitization

Is stripping leading '/' and disallowing '../' in any part of a user-supplied file-name still considered 'safe'? Or is there some (utf-8 encoding comes to mind) way around that? I'm not asking if the filename can be created on every filesystem. I'd like to retain as much user-input as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should clean characters forbidden in filenames for the filesystem you use (do not forget \ , because it can cause some problems in windows environments... and can provide some escaping characters problems...)

But you can allways change the filename to some sequence you create and then, map the filename versus this new name in the database... With this you can keep whatever name you like (be carefull when listing to avoid XSS and so on...)